# Performance degrades for more than 2 threads on Xeon X5355

Tags: multicore

I am writing an application using boost threads and using boost barriers to synchronize the threads. I have two machines to test the application.

Machine 1 is a core2 duo (T8300) cpu machine (windows XP professional - 4GB RAM)  where I am getting following performance figures :

**Number of threads :1   , TPS :21**

**Number of threads :2  ,  TPS :35 (66 % improvement)**

further increase in number of threads decreases the TPS but that is understandable as the  machine  has only two cores.

Machine 2 is a 2 quad core ( Xeon X5355) cpu machine (windows 2003 server with 4GB RAM) and has 8 effective cores.

**Number of threads :1   , TPS :21**

**Number of threads :2  ,  TPS :27 (28 % improvement)**

**Number of threads :4  ,  TPS :25**

**Number of threads :8  ,  TPS :24**

As you can see, performance is degrading after 2 threads (though it has 8 cores). If the program has some bottle neck , then for 2 thread also it should have degraded.

Any idea? , Explanations ? , Does the OS has some role in performance ? -  It seems like the Core2duo (2.4GHz) scales better than Xeon X5355 (2.66GHz)  though it has better clock speed.

Thank you

-Zoolii

Comment: How are you measuring TPS? Do you have any other perf information like % CPU Utilisation or CPU Queue length etc?

Comment: This really belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you sure you're threads are fully independent of each other? I don't know the Boost library, but if it does automatic mutex locking on global variables, you could easily create a lock bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very surprised if this isn't memory page access related. Have you tried forcing the Xein box down to four or two CPUs and rerun you tests?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to do more analysis. E.g. how much contention is there? How many times do the cores block on flushing cache for the memory barriers?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the sole difference between the two machines is the CPU you really have no way of knowing.  Subtle interactions between bus speeds, memory, disk I/O (if relevant), network I/O (if relevant), 32 bit vs 64 bit (if relevant), device drivers and the OS could all contribute to this.

One thing you might check is System Properties | Advanced | Performance Settings | Advanced and ensure that the "Processor scheduling" on both machines is the same; at least it will remove one difference.